# How can i cast nested generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, boxing

First of all i'm using Unity, which won't support any of the latest features like [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netcore-3.1) or [Cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netcore-3.1) of IEnumerables.

I have an abstract class `Item` and another class `Sword` and `Hammer`, which both inherit from `Item`.
I also have a struct `ItemHolder`.

```
public struct ItemHolder<ItemType> where ItemType : Item {
    public ItemType Item {get; set;}
}
```

I have two lists `List<ItemHolder<Sword>> swordList` and other `List<ItemHolder<Hammer>> hammerList` and want to generate a list of type `List<ItemHolder<Item>>`, which contains all elements of the other lists casted to `ItemHolder<Item>`.

I tried this code snippet:

```
public List<ItemHolder<Item>> GetAllItems() {
    List<ItemHolder<Item>> allItems = new List<ItemHolder<Item>>();

    List<ItemHolder<Item>> swordItemList = 
        CastListElementsToType<ItemHolder<Sword>, ItemHolder<Item>>(swordList);
    
    //do the same thing for the hammers and add all elements to allItems.

    return allItems;
}

private List<To> CastListElementsToType<From, To>(List<From> list) where From : To {
    List<To> result = new List<To>();

    foreach (From element in list) {
        result.Add((To) element);
    }

    return result;
}
```

but it tells me, that there is no boxing conversion avaliable from `ItemHolder<Sword>` to `ItemHolder<Item>`.

Is there any way to solve this or do i need a completely new appraoch?

Comment: First of all, `Linq` is available from .NET 3.5, you can use `Except` and `Cast` methods. Second, it's a good approach to start a generic type parameters from capital `T` letter, like `public struct ItemHolder<TItemType> where TItemType : Item`. Last point - is there any reason that `ItemHolder` is a struct?

Comment: I saw that it should be avaliable in .NET 3.5, but even when setting the API Compatabilty Level to .NET 4.x in unity i dont have access to these methods. Thanks for pointing out that i should use The `TItemType` convention. And it's a struct because i wanted to use structs as much as possible to have less data in the heap and less garbage collector overhead, but yes since this is a pretty small struct i could also make a class out of it.

Comment: This is a variance issue. Just because `Sword` inherits from `Item`, doesn't mean that `ItemHolder<Sword>` inherits from `ItemHolder<Item>`; it doesn't. You could create a covariant interface e.g. `IItemHolder<out ItemType> where ItemType : Item`, but that is a reference type, unlike your struct.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay thanks, this solves this problem. I'm not sure, if i will make an Interface for ItemHolder or just change the structure of the entire code, since this seems like a lot for such a small issue.